# Can "to be able to" be used in perfect infinitive?

Tags: tenses, time, perfect-infinitive

I understand the use of perfect infinitive. The thing is that I find it awful to use "to be able to" referring to something that happened in the past.

Let me elaborate with an example I just read: I am very fortunate to be able to have visited other countries such as Colombia or Brazil.

Wouldn't it be better to say "I am very fortunate to HAVE BEEN ABLE TO VISIT other countries such as..."

For me, it sounds more natural, and the time reference does not strike me as...twisted. I don't know if what bugs me is the use of two infinitives consecutively, or I don't know.

Anyhow, would love some light be thrown in the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right it would be hard to be able (now) to have visited somewhere in the past.  The ability to travel happens when we travel, not later.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that your modified version is more pleasant to the ear. It's less verbose.

1. *"I am very fortunate to be able to have visited other countries such as Colombia or Brazil."*
2. **"I am very fortunate to have been able to visit other countries such as Colombia or Brazil."**
3. **"I was very fortunate to be able to visit other countries such as Colombia or Brazil."**

**EDITS:** I am making edits per the comments b/c someone really wanted to point out that the first option above is not technically correct. I agree it's not *perfectly* structured English b/c of the tense of "have visited" with "to be able to". Technically speaking it should be "was able to" and the tense of *visited* changed to *visit* dropping *have*.

**The second OR third sentences above are correct.** The trouble with the first is the fact that you can't have these together: "have visited" (past) and "to be able to" (present). It will pass muster in AmE if you said it aloud.

The second and third sentences are more clear, direct, and *technically* grammatically correct. At any rate, "to be able to" is unidiomatic in that first context and sounds strange because we are not used to hearing it this way. "To have been able" is more idiomatic and makes more sense with things that have already occurred. Or you can change it to "was able to" and modify the tense of "visited".

**NOTE:** I don't like overthinking grammar syntax. English syntax is very meld-able and driven by the masses; it's very nature is completely subjective. We make the rules. There is not some science that dictates what is right or wrong. There are no scientific tests, empirical data, or hypothesis we can use to determine which are right or wrong in the universe (aside from what the populace at large uses in everyday speech). What you need to do is learn the syntactic structure and rules of your language and then begin to learn how it's actually used in your particular locale. There are many idiosyncrasies in every language of the world and nothing involving linguistics is a *law* or *set in stone*.

Comment: Kace36, I think you're mistaken. I think your thought *I am very fortunate to be able to have visited other countries such as Colombia or Brazil* would have to be expressed as *I was very fortunate to be able to visit…*

Comment: Kace, this is silly. Show us your ngram for *(to) be able to have visited* or recognise that it's simply wrong.

Comment: And to be clear this is why I'm not a huge fan of syntactical grammarianism. It's unlike math and is subjective in nature. 2+2=4. There is no arguing that. However I could take this (many others I see too) and argue them to the moon with various subjective interpretations. I don't say that only because of this post, as I do agree with you more on this one. But in general I see it so often. Example: I corrected myself last night on a post I glossed over before commenting, after Kris pointed it out and answered, then another guy came along and challenged his answer. It's like "oy!". SMH.

Comment: Uh… why would you remove the first option?

How do you disagree?

I’m not sure what you mean by *ding you* and there are dozens of millions of native speakers in the US and every other english-speaking country who know your example is wrong.

It’s not remotely obvious that the OP read it somewhere; didn’t you realize huge numbers of ELU posts are artificial constructs. 

Could you please just drop the illusion that *I am fortunate to be able to have visited…* could ever be correct?

Comment: Thanks, Kace. I'm not at all being 'hostile'. I'm just pointing out that what you said wasn't correct.

Remember when you said 2+2=4? That does apply, but not the way you hoped it would.

Please, stop digging the hole deeper. Please.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I had an edited version but my internet went out. Been on phone since I tried to hit the Post Edit button. Please you are being kinda passive aggressive now. I dont know why. I saved my updated answer on my desktop. As soon as my internet is restored I will update the answer. But I still feel grammarrian pedantics are a bit absurd (this is  not a shot not aimed at you but many things I see on this site). It's not science. You go by what your audience and the locale will accept. It changes. It molds. That was my point. Anyway I will update when I don't have to use my phone ok.

Comment: Kace, how exactly do any of those circumstances affect the grammar we’re talking about, please?

I am not being any kind of aggressive. I’m still simply pointing out that what you said was not correct.

If you can explain how *I am fortunate to be able to have visited (anywhere)* is justifiable, please do.

Otherwise, please acknowledge that it’s not.

Comment: Did you mean to say you'd edited your answer? Sorry I failed to see that.

Could you please stop carping and recognise that what might *pass muster in AmE if said aloud* is a slip-shod explanation, at very best?.

Sorry, and your edited answer will confuse everyone who didn't already know all this, but fail to convince anyone who did.

As the man said, Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Kace, could you please simply recognize that this has nothing to do with anything being *more pleasant to the ear* or *less verbose* or anything remotely like that?

Elias's question was wholly reasonable and Yosef's answer was wholly correct.

*… to be able to have visited…* might just be acceptable in some circumstances and in this one, it is not.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Rob I have already updated my answer. I have even deleted my comments to keep this post cleaner so it's not a long mess. What do you want? The answer is updated. Plain and simple. What difference does it make if I agree with you in comments? I disagree. I have heard many people speak those very words, and sentences very similar, all across America, popular media, etc... You can even google it for christs sake and find that that phrase it typed often (also put in blogs). It wouldn't show up in google's semantic algorithms if it weren't! I mean come on.

Comment: The point originally was that it's not some *crazy* thing that people are going to notice. And they wouldn't Rob. I totally disagree. However, I *still* updated the answer - for you. What's the problem?

Comment: Well, Kace, if that's your standard then I guess that's your standard and good luck with it.